# Redirect all the .php files of root folder (old URLs) to new folder, with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect all the `.php` files of root directory (old URLs) to the same files which have been moved to a new directory (new URLs), with .htaccess.

e.g.:

`something.com/handsome.php`, `something.com/index.php`

to

`something.com/fold/handsome.php`, `something.com/fold/index.php`

etc. Also:

`something.com/hector/handsome.php`

to

`something.com/fold/hector/handsome.php`

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is _not_ a free coding service. We are here to help each other with _specific programming questions_, so issues with your code. We are _not_ here to do your work for you. So start yourself, if the stuff is unfamiliar for you, then read some tutorials, the documentation and some examples. Then, if you run into a specific issue with _your_ code, then is the time to ask here and post your code along with your question. This is clearly explained, I suggest you read through the local tour to see how this site works: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Kitty: Have you tried anything to solve this?

Comment: Hi! Remember to mark one of the answers below as accepted, if any solved the problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax for you would be:

```
Redirect 301 /handsome.php http://www.something.com/fold/handsome.php
Redirect 301 /index.php http://www.something.com/fold/index.php
Redirect 301 /hector/handsome.php http://www.something.com/fold/hector/handsome.php
```

in the `.htaccess` file. Further detalis here: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/redirects/.

Answer (score -1):

Redirect using htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 something.com/handsome.php(.*) something.com/index.php$1

RedirectMatch 301 something.com/fold/handsome.php(.*) something.com/fold/index.php$1

RedirectMatch 301 something.com/hector/handsome.php(.*) something.com/fold/hector/handsome.php$1
```

You can redirect using htaccess tools
http://www.webconfs.com/htaccess-redirect-generator.php